# Cumulative difference formula

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, cumulative-sum

I have a a table that calculates the optimal cost allocation against a specific resource by hour and then distributes that data based on the results.  The allocation works wonders but my issue lies when there are multiple rows that have the same hour.  I have not been able to create a formula in Excel that can take into account previous rows and then subtract the amount used from the available resource.  If all of a resource has been used up, it should default to the next available resource.  Here is the current formula:

```
=IF(Q2=0,"NONE",INDEX('RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!$F$3:$I$3,1,MATCH(LARGE(INDIRECT("'RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!F"&B2+3&" :I"&B2+3),1),INDIRECT("'RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!F"&B2+3&" :I"&B2+3),0)))
```

`Q2` = The first cell with a number in it

`Resource Allocation` is a worksheet in this workbook where the range `$F$3:$I$3` are the available resources by name.

The `MATCH` formula simply looks at the current row's hour, points it to the corresponding row in the table and then returns the associated resource by name.

Each subsequent row increases by one like so:

```
=IF(Q3=0,"NONE",INDEX('RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!$F$3:$I$3,1,MATCH(LARGE(INDIRECT("'RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!F"&B3+3&" :I"&B3+3),1),INDIRECT("'RESOURCE ALLOCATION'!F"&B3+3&" :I"&B3+3),0)))
```

The table I am using looks like:

```
Hour Resource 1 Resource 2  Resource 3  Resource 4    TOTAL

  21         50          0           0           10    60
```

For this hour, there are `60` units required. `50` allocated against `Resource 1` and `10` allocated against `Resource 4`.  Under the current formula it just allocates everything against `Resource 1`.

Comment: It's not clear to me (a) what your trying to do, and (2) where you're falling short. Could you add some sample data or an image of relevant parts of your spreadsheets to get me up to speed?

Comment: For hour 21, there are 50 available units on Resource 1 and 283 available units on Resource 4.  There are two deals that occur this hour, deal A is for 20 units and deal B is for 40 units.  The output I would like to see would be the first 20 units of deal A allocated against Resource 1, the next 30 units of deal B allocated against Resource 1 and the final 10 units of deal B allocated against Resource 4.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to add a parameter that checks for duplicate hours in the current formula.  I can use COUNTIF to find duplicates but then I am unsure how to have subsequent formulas return a different value based on what hours have already been used.  I am trying to avoid using vba if possible, but if it is simpler I may have to create a macro.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

[image: Solution]

I have added a few additional columns for legibility.

In column C you have simple sumifs checking amount spent for this particular hour for a given cell and all the preceding ones.

Formula in C2:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2)
```

Column D is just range that will go into INDIRECT function.

Formula in D2:

```
="I"&MATCH(A2,H:H,0)&":L"&MATCH(A2,H:H,0)
```

Column E shows a resource that has been used as the 1st source for this particular hour and its occurrence.

Formula in E2:

```
=5-IFERROR((1/(A2=A1))*IFERROR(MATCH(C1,INDIRECT(D2),0)-1,MATCH(C1,INDIRECT(D2),-1)),4)
```

Column F shows a resource that has been used as the last source for this particular hour and its occurrence. Returns error if there are not enough resources (I do not know if it might be the case).

Formula in F2:

```
=5-MATCH(C2,INDIRECT(D2),-1)
```

---

Summary:

The idea is quite simple but if requires you to change your approach. The accumulation should occur within the resources rather than in the final report table. R4 should be a sum of actual resource 4 and all the other resources i.e. R4 = resource 4 + resource 3 + resource 2 + resource 1, R3 = resource 3 + resource 2 + resource 1, R2 = resource 2 + resource 1, R1 = resource 1. And having that simply use matching with argument -1.

Since you don't have all the resources you might want to add some kind of exclusion to the range that is being reported as the 1st and the last used resources.

Comment: "Returns error if there are not enough resources (I do not know if it might be the case)."  

There will never not be enough resources, think of it like a bank account where Account 1 has $50 available / hour , account 2 has $100 available / hour and so on.  Account 1 always takes priority so if you made a purchase for $70 dollars then $50 would be allocated against account 1 and $20 would be allocated against account 2. 

Next hour if you made a purchase for $100, $50 is allocated against account 1 and $50 against account 2 and so on.

Comment: The error occurs if the sum of all purchases in a given hour is more than the sum of all available resources for this hour. In your example there will be no error. Look at the cell F6 - the error occurred because you wanted to spent 30 units after having already spent 120 when your total limit of all resources together was 135. I think that my solution does what you wanted.